# is there any method or api available to create unique referral link for telegram bot with python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, refer

I'm trying to create bot in python with referral feature but I didn't get any method to create referral links for user in telegram docs. can you suggest any alternative approach for it. so that we can create a link and any new member can follow that link to start bot and referral got registered in referrers account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Deep Linking](https://core.telegram.org/bots#deep-linking) feature which allows you to add a custom parameter for your convenience

```
https://t.me/my_telegram_bot?start=ref01
```

The user will be sent to the Bot and, after clicking on Start, the value `ref01` is passed to the start command handler.

Comment: Thanks Beppe, I tried this method but as you said that it just pass parameters as a update query and from there we can set conditions and manipulate incoming update to store there referral link (ref01). And it's satisfied all my needs but I need to create additional database to store referrals links or referer , refree sets.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use some redirect method in your webserver code.

1. Generate the referral link and save in some storage
2. When user open the link, after check method redirect to bot